# Wok Cooking on a Home Stove

Tags: equipment, asian-cuisine, stove, wok

I work with woks at work and know about the wok pit used to cook on for heat, to hold the rounded bottom, and to toss the food. Is there a tool or way to use my at home gas stove for my wok (specifically round bottom) or would I have to install a wok pit.

I know of flat bottoms and have one of them as well but I'm dissatisfied with them.

Comment: Depends on the stove but on some you can remove the grate.

Comment: I can but there's still the burner there and it wouldn't fix the stand issue

Comment: I use something called Wok Ring Stand. You can buy them online. I made mine from a steel bowl because it was faster than waiting for delivery.

Answer (score 3):

You can find flat bottom woks that work on flat ranges effectively. They are sub-optimal though, as they don't evenly distribute the heat across the sides. In this use a high sided saute pan is just as useful. I have heard of mounts that sit over a burner as well. These are usually useless for home-use because stove heat output is too low.

A [wok ring stand](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=6DNRW5W7N4S1ggfpsJr4CQ&q=wok%20ring%20stand&oq=wok%20ring%20stand&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1.1458.5859.0.6051.17.14.0.1.1.0.104.1119.12j1.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.14.1135.0..0i131k1.61.Lum0mV4Q0mA) will work with most(gas) stovetops and will make your rounded bottom wok usable. They still aren't ideal though because the heat output is still focused on the lower apex of the pan and the sides get much less. therefor heat distribution is still off.

There are also small individual wok burners that run on propane. but most of them are large (think outdoor grill size) and may/or may not, be the solution you need.

Comment: I read that a lot of wok ring stands are unstable?

Comment: @JadeSo They are often flimsy pieces of crap that deteriorate from exposure to frequent heat. I wouldn't buy one because I have been dissatisfied with the results of using one (as pointed out, poor heat distribution) but if I were to buy one I would absolutely do comparison shopping to make sure I got one that would hold up over time.

Comment: I had to weld my own ring stands to get one that actually worked.